# Html shows after submitting form and is nowhere to be found in php script

Tags: php, html, forms

Upon submitting this form on my site. It send me to a page that says.

> "Use Back - fill in all fields Use
>   back! ! "

But this html isn't in the mail script anywhere. Where could this be coming from? I started out using this contact form (http://www.ibdhost.com/contact/) then changed it a little.

Here is the mail script.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sendemail Script</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Reminder: Add the link for the 'next page' (at the bottom) -->
<!-- Reminder: Change 'YourEmail' to Your real email -->
<?php
//the 3 variables below were changed to use the SERVER variable
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$httpref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$httpagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$visitorf = $_POST['visitorf'];
$visitorl = $_POST['visitorl'];
$visitormail = $_POST['visitormail'];
$visitorphone = $_POST['visitorphone'];
//$notes = $_POST['notes'];
//$attn = $_POST['attn'];
$lookup = array(
    'The Election Report' => 'http://www.mydowmain.net/',
    '5 Resons' => 'http://www.mydomain.net/',
 'Report 3' => 'http://someotherurl3.com/',
 'Report 4' => 'http://someotherurl4.com/',
 'Report 5' => 'http://someotherurl5.com/',
    // et cetera for your other values
);

$attn = trim($_POST['attn']);
$url = $lookup[$attn];
//echo 'attn: ' . $attn . ', url:' . $url; die;

//additional headers 
$headers = 'From: US <info@mailinator.net>' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'BCC: kelbizzle@mailinator.com' . "\r\n";

$todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;
$subject = "your lead has downloaded a report.";
$subjectdp = "Someone has downloaded a report!";
$notes = stripcslashes($notes);
$message = "Dear PAl Affiliate,\n\nA prospective lead of yours has downloaded a report from our Website.\nAny contact information they have left and a link to the report they downloaded\ncan be found below. This is the perfect opportunity for you to open up a line of\ncommunication with the prospect and find out their intrests! If you have any questions\nabout this email please feel free to email us at info@mailinaot.net\n\n\nFrom: $visitorf $visitorl ($visitormail)\nTelephone Number: $visitorphone \nReport Downloaded:$url\n \n\nBest regards,\nThe Crew";
//$message = "$todayis [EST] \nAttention:  \nMessage: $notes \nFrom: $visitorf $visitorl ($visitormail) \nTelephone Number: //$visitorphone \nReport Downloaded:$url\nAdditional Info : IP = $ip \nBrowser Info: $httpagent \nReferral : $httpref\n";
$messagedp = "A Visitor has just downloaded a report. You can find their contact information below.\n
\n
***********************************************************************\n
From: $visitorf $visitorl\n
Email: $visitormail\n
Telephone Number: $visitorphone \n
Report Downloaded:$url\n
\n
\n
Best regards,\n
The Crew\n";
$messagelead = "Dear, $visitorf\n
\n
\n
We appreciate your interest. Below you will find the URL to download the report you requested.\n
Things are always changing in costa rica , so check back often. Also, check us out on Facebook & Twitter \n
for daily updates. If there is anything we can do at anytime to enhance your experience, please do\n
not hesitate to  contact us.\n
\n
To download your report simply click on the link below. (You must have Adobe Reader or an alternative PDF reader installed)\n
\n
*** Download Link ***\n
$url\n";
//check if the function even exists
if(function_exists("mail"))
{
 //send the email
 mail($_SESSION['email'], $subject, $message, $headers) or die("could not send email");
} else {
     die("mail function not enabled");
    } 
     //send the email to us
     mail('info@mailinator.com', $subjectdp, $messagedp);
     //send the email to the lead
     mail($visitormail, 'Thanks for downloading the report!', $messagelead, $headers);

    header( "Location: http://www.mydomain.com/thanks_report.php" );
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you have in your thanks_report.php file?

Comment: *It send me to a page that says* - which page? Have you wrote the page yourself?

Comment: the thank_report.php file is just a page they get forwarded to that says thanks for filling out the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the page you linked (an interesting shade of pink I might add ;) ), you have a `sendeail.php` (though I assume it's `sendemail.php`) and in that it contains the code:

```
if(empty($visitor) || empty($visitormail) || empty($notes )) {
   echo "<h2>Use Back - fill in all fields</h2>\n";
   die ("Use back! ! "); 
}
```

You are implying that you've modified the above code to do what you want it to do, but did you change the location of the form POST on the page before? e.g. the example on your link posts to the page stated, if you haven't updated that link to point to your new version - then it would account for this error. (A side note, you probably should make sure that you've refreshed the page with the user-completed form on it too).

Comment: Yes, the form is on reports_test.php and the location of the form post is sendemail_reports.php. I've updated the link. I want to add also that I removed the block of code you mentioned from the sendemail_reports.php

Comment: Then other than caching issues and quadruple checking everything, I'm not sure what to suggest without maybe seeing the HTML form prior to this (and even that may be a long shot). :(

Comment: caching may be the issue. but I also tried it with ie8 as well. 

Here is a link to the html form 

http://preview.tinyurl.com/yap97jx

Comment: I cleared the cache and it seemed to work fine. I didn't think it would cache that small bit but it does make sense. I got the notification you downloaded the report. I said oh crap I better go select an answer. Thank you very much!